# Unable to calculate canonical name to bundle file ‘///twenty/two/2/.js’, Aurelia bundler

Tags: javascript, bundling-and-minification, aurelia

I am getting an error on bundling my [aurelia](http://aurelia.io/) app.

> Error is : Unable to calculate canonical name to bundle file
>   ‘///twenty/two/2/.js’

Following is my `Config.js` content

```js
 "baseURL": "/src/",
 "defaultJSExtensions": true,
 "transpiler": "babel",
 "babelOptions": {
   "optional": [
     "runtime",
     "optimisation.modules.system",
     "es7.decorators",
     "es7.classProperties"
   ]
 },
 "paths": {
   "*": "*",
   "github:": "jspm_packages/github/",
   "npm:": "jspm_packages/npm/",
   "resources/": "resources/",
   "account/": "account/",
   "activity/": "activity/",
   "dashboard/": "dashboard/",
   "feedback/": "feedback/",
   "home/": "home/",
   "orders/": "orders/",
   "shared/": "shared/",
   "user/": "user/"
 },
```

Following is the build/bundles.json

```js
{
  "bundles": {
    "dist/app-build": {
      "includes": [
        "[*/**/*]",
        "[*/**/*.html!text]",
        "[*/**/*.css!text]"
      ],
      "excludes": [],
      "options": {
        "inject": true,
        "minify": true
      }
    },
    "dist/aurelia": {
      "includes": [
        "aurelia-animator-css",
        "aurelia-auth",
        "aurelia-binding",
        "aurelia-bootstrapper",
        "aurelia-breeze",
        "aurelia-dependency-injection",
        "aurelia-dialog",
        "aurelia-event-aggregator",
        "aurelia-framework",
        "aurelia-history",
        "aurelia-history-browser",
        "aurelia-http-client",
        "aurelia-i18n",
        "aurelia-loader",
        "aurelia-loader-default",
        "aurelia-logging",
        "aurelia-metadata",
        "aurelia-path",
        "aurelia-route-recognizer",
        "aurelia-router",
        "aurelia-task-queue",
        "aurelia-templating",
        "aurelia-templating-binding",
        "aurelia-templating-resources",
        "aurelia-templating-router",
        "aurelia-validation",
        "babel",
        "bootstrap",
        "breeze",
        "core-js",
        "css",
        "font-awesome",
        "i18next",
        "jquery",
        "moment",
        "ms-signalr-client",
        "text",
        "toastr"
      ],
      "options": {
        "inject": true,
        "minify": true,
        "rev": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please help me to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Doesn't seem like an aurelia error but a systemjs one. Please check https://github.com/systemjs/builder/issues/451